# Keras - cannot convert numpy array to tensor object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv') # training data
dfeval = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv') # testing data
y_train = dftrain.pop('survived')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('survived')

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[9]),  # input layer (1)
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),  # hidden layer (2)
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax') # output layer (3)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dftrain, y_train, epochs=10)
```

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for         sex   age  n_siblings_spouses  ...     deck  embark_town alone
0      male  22.0                   1  ...  unknown  Southampton     n
1    female  38.0                   1  ...        C    Cherbourg     n
2    female  26.0                   0  ...  unknown  Southampton     y
3    female  35.0                   1  ...        C  Southampton     n
4      male  28.0                   0  ...  unknown   Queenstown     y
..      ...   ...                 ...  ...      ...          ...   ...
622    male  28.0                   0  ...  unknown  Southampton     y
623    male  25.0                   0  ...  unknown  Southampton     y
624  female  19.0                   0  ...        B  Southampton     y
625  female  28.0                   1  ...  unknown  Southampton     n
626    male  32.0                   0  ...  unknown   Queenstown     y

[627 rows x 9 columns] with type DataFrame

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

I am getting this error!
this is a data frame that predicts if a person survived or not.
could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem??
advance thanks!
Click here this link to see the dataframe that i tried to upload as train features.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQYSW.png)

model.summary() =[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc1xz.png)

Comment: can you post the `model.summary()`

Comment: Also, why are you passing categorical features as text to the neural network? you have to convert these features as encodings (one hot or something).

Comment: yes i edited my question and included the model.summary()

Comment: hey akshay,thanks for your help, you mean that i should covert these dataframe into tensorflow dataset object before i pass that into the model.train ?

Comment: its not about converting datatype. neural networks cant handle text data. you have to use One-hot encoding or similar methods to convert categorical columns into numeric.

Comment: Please read this and follow this step by step. https://www.kaggle.com/alexo22/simple-but-solid-neural-network-for-top-10-result

Comment: Read this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-categorical-input-handling-for-neural-networks-c172ba552dee) to understand why and how you handle different datatypes for neural networks.

Comment: aaah makes sense,thanks bro!! let me try that

Comment: Sure, i have added a detailed answer below. please refer to that.

Comment: brooo it worked!!!! thanks akshay!!

Comment: how do i accept your answer?

Comment: click the tick mark next to answer. that should mark it :) (under the upvote buttons)

Comment: Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPTQC.png) or take a [tour] of the website to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural networks cant handle text features. You will have to use an [One-hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) or other forms of encodings to transform the categorical features to numeric.

Similarly, for ordinal features, you want to use [Label encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

Please read [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-categorical-input-handling-for-neural-networks-c172ba552dee) for understanding why and how each of these inputs is handled for neural networks, and if you may want to follow a guide on how to use neural network to classify over the titanic dataset. One such link is [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/alexo22/simple-but-solid-neural-network-for-top-10-result).